# Node js app hosting options

Tags: sitecore-managed-cloud

Can I deploy and manage my Nodejs app in "Sitecore Managed Cloud"? Are there tooling (UI or API or both) to manage my frond-end environments and headless environments in the same Cloud platform?

Comment: This is probably a question you need to ask your Sitecore Rep and check it against your Managed Cloud contract.

Comment: If I have the access to "Sitecore Manager Cloud", does it mean that I do not have to worry about provisioning or high-availability or other platform considerations (except performance) when I or my team develops a nodejs app?

All I have to do is approach Sitecore Rep - is that correct?